# Using a label printer on a print server and the print constantly comes out microscopic.

Tags: network-printer

I am using a StarTech print server.  I have tried using both Dymo LabelWriter 400 and a SII SLP 400 with the same result.

It prints microscopic(Totally unreadable).  I've tried everything I can think of.

Please help.

Comment: Please provide more details. Os etc.

Comment: We use windows XP professional SP3.

Comment: I had the same problem with USB connected Dymo Labelwriter Twin turbo, But I got that to print normal. Just can't get either of the printers I've tried on the print server to print normal.